# The entity type was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm new to ASP.NET Core and i'm trying to insert an entity into an Entity Framework Core model scaffolded from a simple existing MariaDB database.

This is the entity model:

```
    public class ScrapeAsincroni
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Paese { get; set; }
        public string Engine { get; set; }
        public string Keywords { get; set; }
    }
```

This is the controller action that is supposed to add the entity:

```
    public JsonResult create(string paese, string engine, string keywords)
        {
            ScrapeAsincroni scrapeAsincrono = new ScrapeAsincroni {
                Paese = paese,
                Engine = engine,
                Keywords = keywords
            };
            _context.Add(scrapeAsincrono);

            try
            {
                _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return Json(new Dictionary<string, int?> { { "id", null } });
            }
            return Json(new Dictionary<string, int?>{ {"id", scrapeAsincrono.Id} });
        }
```

The database context (_context) has been initialized on the controller's constructor.
the line

```
 _context.Add(scrapeAsincrono);
```

throws the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'ScrapeAsincroni' was not found. Ensure that the entity type has been added to the model.

This is the modelBuilder code relative to this model

```
   public partial class ScraperDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public ScraperDbContext()
        {
        }

        public ScraperDbContext(DbContextOptions<ScraperDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<ScrapeAsincroni> ScrapeAsincroni { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                #warning To protect potentially sensitive information in your connection string, you should move it out of source code. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=723263 for guidance on storing connection strings.
                optionsBuilder.UseMySql("server=#.#.#.#;port=####;user=####;password=####;database=####", x => x.ServerVersion("10.3.25-mariadb"));
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<ScrapeAsincroni>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasComment("Informazioni su una ricerca asincrona dello Scraper");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id)
                    .HasColumnName("id")
                    .HasColumnType("int(11)");

                entity.Property(e => e.Engine)
                    .HasColumnName("engine")
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(255)")
                    .HasCharSet("utf8")
                    .HasCollation("utf8_general_ci");

                entity.Property(e => e.Keywords)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasColumnName("keywords")
                    .HasColumnType("text")
                    .HasCharSet("utf8")
                    .HasCollation("utf8_general_ci");

                entity.Property(e => e.Paese)
                    .HasColumnName("paese")
                    .HasColumnType("varchar(255)")
                    .HasCharSet("utf8")
                    .HasCollation("utf8_general_ci");
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }

        partial void OnModelCreatingPartial(ModelBuilder modelBuilder);
    }
```

I can't seem to understand why this happens, and couldn't find any solutions online.

Comment: Do you have a `DbSet<ScrapeAsincroni>` property in your context?

Comment: maybe you don't have a `virtual DbSet<ScrapeAsincroni> ScrapeAsincronis` property in your context if it's already there then try `_context.ScrapeAsincronis.Add(scrapeAsincrono);`

Comment: I do have that field, i will update the question with the entire context class

Answer (score 5):

It was, of course, a trivial error that i would fix the next day. I was using the base DbContext class, while i should have used the custom database context class which i defined when scaffolding the database.
This is how the context was instantiated before in the controller script:

```
        private readonly DbContext _context;
        public ScrapeAsincroniController(DbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
```

now it is:

```
        private readonly ScraperDbContext _context;
        public ScrapeAsincroniController(ScraperDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
```

I also changed this line in startup.cs:

```
 services.AddDbContext<ScraperDbContext>(options => options
                .UseMySql("<your_connection_string>",
                mysqlOptions => mysqlOptions.ServerVersion(new Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Storage.ServerVersion(new Version(10, 3, 25), ServerType.MariaDb))
                )
            );
```

Answer (score 4):

add

```
public DbSet<ScrapeAsincroni> ScrapeAsincronis { get; set; }
```

in your context file for adding an entity to your model.